# How many vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A sequence of vectors $\mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{2}, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_{k}$ from a vector space $V$ is said to be linearly dependent, if there exist scalars $a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{k},$ not all zero, such that
\begin{equation*}
a_{1} \mathbf{v}_{1}+a_{2} \mathbf{v}_{2}+\cdots+a_{k} \mathbf{v}_{k}=\mathbf{0}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{0}$ denotes the zero vector.

Suppose we have $\mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{2}, \mathbf{v}_{3}$ such that $a_{1} \mathbf{v}_{1}+a_{2} \mathbf{v}_{2}+a_{3} \mathbf{v}_{3}=\mathbf{0}$ has solution $a_3=-2a_2 + 4a_1$. How many linearly independent vectors is there in the set $\{\mathbf{v}_{1}, \mathbf{v}_{2}, \mathbf{v}_{3}\}$ ? I feel like if the solution was $a_3=-2a_2$, $a_1 =0$, the answer would be $2$ ($\mathbf{v}_{1}$ and another one). Is it still $2$ for the above case ? Or 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concerns are in the right place, as the "solution" $a_3=-2a_2+4a_1$ lack some information. If by this terminology you also say that $v_1,v_2$ are lineary independent (and hence there is need to state $a_2$ AND $a_1$, then the answer is as you said, $2$.
But there is the option that for example $v_1 = \alpha v_2$ which means that actualy $v3 = (-2+4\alpha)v1$ and hence there is one independent vector in the set

Answer (score 0):

There could be:

- 0 linearly independent vectors

```
all vectors are 0
```

- 1 linearly independent vector

```
1 non zero vector and 2 zero vectors
2 non zero vectors that lie on the same line and 1 zero vector
3 non zero vectors that lie on the same line
```

- 2 linearly independent vectors

```
1 non zero vector, 1 linearly independent vector, 1 zero vector
2 non zero vectors that lie on the same line and 1 non zero vector not on the same line
1 nonzero vector, 1 nonzero vector that doesn't lie on the same line, and 1 nonzero
     vector that lies in the plane but not on the same line as either of those vectors
```

- 3 linearly independent vectors

```
the dimension of the vector space must be at least 3, and the vectors are linearly
     independent (the coefficients of them are all 0)
```